# How to multiple call to an api with jquery and collect the results in an array?

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I am trying to use Tumblr api to collect posts from my different tumblogs. I use [jquery tumblr plugin](https://github.com/alexhayes/jquery-tumblr) to do it but the results comes separated for each tumblogs. I want to collect this results in to one array than render this in html to sort with date... Can someone show me a direction to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the jquery tumblr plugin to have some callback functions.

Try replacing the contents of your plugin with this...

You will need to write some callback functions and create your tumblr instance like this...

```
var myResults = new Array();
var successCount = 0;
function tumblr_OnSuccess(posts) {
    $(posts).children().each(function (i, item) {
        myResults.push($(item).html());
    });

    successCount++;

    if (successCount == 6) {
        var d = $('<div></div>');

        $(myResults).each(function (i, item) {
            d.append(item);
        });
        $('body').append(d);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<div></div>').tumblr({ url: 'http://kittenskittenskittens.tumblr.com', onSuccess: tumblr_OnSuccess });
    $('<div></div>').tumblr({ url: 'http://kittenskittenskittens.tumblr.com', onSuccess: tumblr_OnSuccess });
    $('<div></div>').tumblr({ url: 'http://kittenskittenskittens.tumblr.com', onSuccess: tumblr_OnSuccess });
    $('<div></div>').tumblr({ url: 'http://kittenskittenskittens.tumblr.com', onSuccess: tumblr_OnSuccess });
    $('<div></div>').tumblr({ url: 'http://kittenskittenskittens.tumblr.com', onSuccess: tumblr_OnSuccess });
    $('<div></div>').tumblr({ url: 'http://kittenskittenskittens.tumblr.com', onSuccess: tumblr_OnSuccess });
});
```

and here is the modified jQuery Tumblr Plugin

```
    /**
 * jQuery tumblr plugin
 * This jQuery plugin was inspired by the work of Chris Tran - https://chris-tran.com/blog/?p=236
 * @name jquery-tumblr-0.2.js
 * @author Alex Hayes - http://alution.com
 * @version 0.3
 * @date Aug 17, 2011
 * @category jQuery plugin
 * @copyright (c) 2011 Alex Hayes (alution.com)
 * @license Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * @todo Add ability to define hooks for user defined markup.
 */
(function( $ ) {

    var methods = {

        /**
         * Initialise the tumblr feed.
         * 
         * @param options     Valid params:
         *                        - url: your tumblr url (ie. http://(YOUR NAME).tumblr.com )
         *                        - loading: A selector that specifies a element that can be shown when loading content from tumblr.
         *                        - pagination: A selector that specifies where the pagination will reside. If one does not exist, pagination is disabled.
         *                        - perPage: The number of posts to return. The default is 20, and the maximum is 50.
         *                        - start: The post offset to start from. The default is 0.
         *                        - paginationOptions: Other options to pass to jquery_pagination - See https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination
         *                        - photoSize: The photo size to use, accepted values are 75, 100, 250, 400, 500 and 1280. Default is 400.
         *                        - videoSize: The video size to embed, accepted values are 250, 500 or false. If false, the tumblr 'video-player' parameter will be used.
         *                        - timeago: If true (default) then jquery-timeago will be used for post dates.
         *                        - shortLength: For captions and titles that are less than this length the css class 'short' will be added. Default is 50.
         *                        - mediumLength: For captions and titles that are less than this length the css class 'medium' will be added. Default is 100.
         *                        - fancybox: If true (default) then fancybox will be used when there are multiple photos. See photoThumbSize and photoLightboxSize
         *                        - photoThumbSize: If there are multiple photos, they will be output in a ul/li tags, this value will be the size of image used. Accepted values are 75, 100, 250, 400, 500 and 1280. Default is 75.
         *                        - photoLightboxSize: If there are multiple photos, this image size will be used for lightbox. Accepted values are 75, 100, 250, 400, 500 and 1280. Default is 1280.
         *                        - timeout: Ajax timeout defaults to 5000
         */
        init : function( options ) {
            var settings = {
                'loading'            : false,
                'pagination'         : false,
                'perPage'            : 20,
                'start'              : 0,
                'paginationOptions'  : {},
                'photoSize'          : 400,
                'videoSize'          : false,
                'timeago'            : true,
                'shortLength'        : 50,
                'mediumLength'       : 100,
                'fancybox'           : true,
                'photoThumbSize'     : 75,
                'photoLightboxSize'  : 500,
                'timeout'            : 10000,
                'onSuccess'          : null,
                'onError'            : null
            };
            var that = this;

            return this.each(function() {        
                // If options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('tumblr'),
                    posts = $('<ul class="tumblr-posts"/>');

                // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                if ( ! data ) {
                    if ( options ) { 
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }
                    if( settings.pagination ) {
                        settings.pagination = $(settings.pagination);
                        if( settings.pagination.length < 1 ) {
                            settings.pagination = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if( settings.loading ) {
                        settings.loading = $(settings.loading);
                        if( settings.loading.length < 1 ) {
                            settings.loading = false;
                        }
                    }
                    $(this).data('tumblr', {
                        target           : $this,
                        start            : settings.start,
                        options          : settings,
                        posts            : posts,
                        pagination_setup : false 
                    });
                }
                $this.tumblr('load');
            });
        },

        /**
         * Load the tumblr feed.
         * 
         * @param Int page    The page number to load (starts at 0).
         */
        load: function(page) {

            // Show all the loaders and slide up the content.
            this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('tumblr');
                if(data.options.loading) {
                    data.options.loading.show();
                }
                $this.slideUp();
            });

            var $this = this, 
                data = this.data('tumblr'),
                params = {
                    start: page == undefined ? data.start * data.options.perPage : page * data.options.perPage,
                    num: data.options.perPage
                },
                url = data.options.url + '/api/read/json?' + $.param(params);               

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'script',
                timeout: data.options.timeout,
                success: function() {
                    $this.tumblr('handleAjaxSuccess', tumblr_api_read);
                },
                error: function (xhr, statusTxt, errorTxt) {
                    // Unlikely that this will be supported because in probably 99.9% of cases it will be cross domain. Will only work if they have setup a tunnel...
                    $this.append(
                        '<h2>Ooops...</h2>' +
                        '<p>It looks like tumblr is having issues - it happens to the best of us. Don\'t worry it should be fixed soon!</p>' +
                        '<p style="display: none;">' + errorTxt + ': ' + xhr.responseText + '</p>'
                    );

                    if (typeof $this.onError == "function")
                        $this.onError(errorTxt, xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            return this;
        },

        handleAjaxSuccess: function(tumblr_api_read) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('tumblr'),
                    posts = data.posts,
                    postIterator = 0;

                data.posts.empty();
                $this.empty();
                if ((tumblr_api_read == undefined) || (tumblr_api_read == null)) {
                    $this.append('<div class="tumblr-error">Unable to load tumblr - its probably down...</div>');
                    return;
                }

                $.each(tumblr_api_read.posts, function(i, post) {
                    $this.tumblr('addPost', post, postIterator);
                    postIterator++;
                });

                if(typeof $.timeago == "function" && data.options.timeago && $("abbr.timeago", data.posts).length > 0) {
                    $("abbr.timeago", data.posts).timeago();
                }
                if(typeof $.fancybox == "function" && data.options.fancybox && $("a.lightbox", data.posts).length > 0) {
                    $("a.lightbox", data.posts).fancybox();
                }
                $this.html(data.posts);
                if(data.options.loading) {
                    data.options.loading.hide();
                }
                $this.slideDown();

                if(data.options.pagination && !data.pagination_setup) {
                    data.pagination_setup = true;
                    $.extend(
                        data.options.paginationOptions, 
                        {
                            items_per_page : data.options.perPage,
                            callback       : function(new_page_index, pagination_container) {
                                $this.tumblr('load', new_page_index);   
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    data.options.pagination.pagination(tumblr_api_read['posts-total'], data.options.paginationOptions);
                }


                if (typeof data.options.onSuccess == "function")
                    data.options.onSuccess(data.posts);
            });
        },

        addPost: function(post, i) {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('tumblr'),
                oddeven = i%2 ? 'even' : 'odd',
                body = '',
                li = '';

            switch(post.type) {
                case "regular": {
                    var extraClass = $this.tumblr('getCssTextLength', post['regular-title']);
                    body = '<div class="title ' + extraClass + '">' + post['regular-title'] + '</div>';
                    if(post['regular-body']) {
                        body += '<div class="description">' + post['regular-body'] + '</div>'; 
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "photo": {
                    body = '<div class="media">';
                    if(post['photos'].length > 0) {
                        body += '<ul class="photos">';
                        $.each(post['photos'], function(i, photo) {
                            var oddeven = i%2 ? 'even' : 'odd';
                            var alt = '';
                            if(photo['photo-caption'] != undefined) {
                                alt = ' alt="' + photo['photo-caption'] + '"'; 
                            }
                            body += '<li class="' + oddeven + '">' +
                                    '<a href="' + photo['photo-url-' + data.options.photoLightboxSize] + '" rel="post-' + post['id'] + '" class="lightbox">' +
                                        '<img src="' + photo['photo-url-' + data.options.photoThumbSize] + '"' + alt + '>' +
                                    '</a>' +
                                '</li>';
                        });
                        body += '</ul>';
                    } else {
                        if(post['photo-link-url']) {
                            body += '<a href="' + post['photo-link-url'] + '">';
                        }
                        body += '<img alt="' + $(post['photo-caption']).text() + '" src="' + post['photo-url-' + data.options.photoSize] + '">';
                        if(post['photo-link-url']) {
                            body += '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                    if(post['photo-caption']) {
                        body += '<div class="description">' + post['photo-caption'] + '</div>';
                    }
                    body += '</div>';
                    break;
                }
                case "link": {
                    var extraClass = $this.tumblr('getCssTextLength', post['link-text']);
                    body = '<div class="link ' + extraClass + '"><a href="' + post['link-url'] + '">' + post['link-text'] + '</a></div>';
                    if(post["link-description"]) {
                        body += '<div class="description">' + post['link-description'] + '</div>';
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "quote": {
                    var extraClass = $this.tumblr('getCssTextLength', post['quote-text']);
                    body = 
                        '<div class="quote">' +
                            '<div class="quote-text ' + extraClass + '">' + post['quote-text'] + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="source">&mdash; ' + post['quote-source'] + '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    break;
                }
                case "conversation": {
                    var extraClass = $this.tumblr('getCssTextLength', post['conversation-title']);
                    body = '<div class="caption ' + extraClass + '">' + post['conversation-title'] + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="conversation">' + '<ul>';

                    var users = [];
                    $.each(post['conversation'], function(i, item) {
                        if( $.inArray(users, item['name']) == -1 ) {
                            users.push(item['name']);
                        }
                        var user = $.inArray(users, item['name']) + 1;
                        body += 
                            '<li class="odd">' + 
                                '<span class="label user-' + user + '">' + item['label'] + '</span>' +
                                '<span class="phrase">' + item['phrase'] + '</span>' +
                            '</li>';
                    });
                    body += '</div>';
                    break;
                }
                case "audio": {
                    body = '<div class="media">' + post['audio-player'] + '</div>';
                    if(post['audio-caption']) {
                        body += '<div class="description">' + post['audio-caption'] + '</div>'; 
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "video": {
                    var player = 'video-player';
                    if(data.options.videoSize) {
                        player = 'video-player-' + data.options.videoSize;
                    }
                    body = '<div class="media">' + post[player] + '</div>';
                    if(post['video-caption']) {
                        body += '<div class="description">' + post['video-caption'] + '</div>';
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;          
            }

            // Add the li to the posts stack.
            li = 
                '<li class="tumblr-post tumblr-post-' + post.type + ' post-id-' + post.id + ' ' + oddeven + '">' +
                    '<div class="post-body">' +
                        body +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="post-footer">' +
                        '<div class="date"><span class="posted">Posted</span> <abbr class="timeago" title="' + post['date'] + '">' + post['date'] + '</abbr></div>' +
                        '<div class="permalink">' +
                            '<a href="' + post['url-with-slug'] + '" class="permalink" target="_blank"><span class="permalink-icon">&#167;</span> <span class="permalink-text">Permalink</span></a>' +
                        '</div>';

            if(post.tags) {
                li += '<div class="tags"><span class="tagged">Tagged </span> <ul>';
                $.each(post.tags, function(i, tag) {
                    var tag_comma = '<span class="tag-commas">, </span>';
                    var extraClass = '';
                    if(i == post.tags.length - 1 ) {
                        extraClass = 'last';
                        tag_comma = '';
                    }
                    else if(i == 0) {
                        extraClass = 'first';
                    }
                    li += '<li class="' + extraClass + '"><a href="' + data.options.url + '/tagged/' + tag +'" target="_blank">#' + tag + '</a>' + tag_comma + '</li>';
                });
                li += '</ul></div>';
            }

            li += '</div>' +
                '</li>';

            data.posts.append(li);
        },

        getCssTextLength: function(text) {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('tumblr'),
                shortLength = data.options.shortLength,
                mediumLength = data.options.mediumLength;

            var extraClass = 'long';
            if(text != null && text.length < shortLength) {
                extraClass = 'short';
            }
            else if(text != null && text.length < mediumLength) {
                extraClass = 'medium';
            }
            return extraClass;
        },

        destroy: function() {
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('tumblr');
                // Namespacing FTW
                $(window).unbind('.tumblr');
                data.posts.remove();
                $this.removeData('tumblr');
            });
        },
    };

    $.fn.tumblr = function( method ) {
        // Method calling logic
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }
    };
})( jQuery );
```